# how to add sub windows that contains QtextEdit in pyqt4

Tags: python, pyqt4, mdi, qtextedit

I am building a text Editor in python using pyqt4 and i want to add sub windows to the mdi Area that should contain a QTextEdit on every click of new(menu Item).So, i want to know how this can be achieved.

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
    MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
    self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
    self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
    self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
    self.mdiArea = QtGui.QMdiArea(self.centralwidget)
    self.mdiArea.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mdiArea"))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.mdiArea, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
    self.menuFile = QtGui.QMenu(self.menubar)
    self.menuFile.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuFile"))
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
    self.actionNew = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.actionNew.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionNew"))
    self.actionExit = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.actionExit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionExit"))
    self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionNew)
    self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionExit)
    self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
    #
    self.Doc_1 = QtGui.QWidget()
    self.Doc_1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Doc_1"))
    self.gridLayout_2 = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.Doc_1)
    self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout_2"))
    self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.Doc_1)
    self.textEdit.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 200))
    self.textEdit.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(741, 16777215))
    self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))
    self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.textEdit, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    #

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.actionExit, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("triggered()")), MainWindow.close)
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.actionNew, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("triggered()")), self.opennew)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
def opennew(self):
    self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(Doc_1);

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
    self.Doc_1.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Doc_1", None))
    self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "file", None))
    self.actionNew.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "new", None))
    self.actionNew.setShortcut(_translate("MainWindow", "Ctrl+N", None))
    self.actionExit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "exit", None))
    self.actionExit.setShortcut(_translate("MainWindow", "Ctrl+X", None))
```

Comment: Hello & welcome to SO. Let us know what you have tried. It will help us help you.

Comment: @emh i have editted my question, you can see what i have tried till now.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Sir, you could have a list of QTextEdit and have your own control on
   it, going forward and backward as you need.**
2. **Another option would be not to have many TextEdit but only save their documents. Each time you click on "New Doc" you would storage its document and reset the current to a new one. Also would need to control it by your self.**
3. *There are many ways to implement it, you just gotta do what would fit better to what you really need. Just got you some ideas.*

*There are many cool tutorials you could go based on.*

[Here](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/building-a-text-editor-with-pyqt-part-one/143) is a really amazing one. Helped me a lot in the very beginning.